# Why is my redux store mapping properties to an object with a single property with the value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

Say my redux store state is `{posts: []}`
In my reducer I return `{posts: [1, 2, 3]`
Then redux tells me the store state is `{posts: {posts: [1, 2, 3]}}`

Here's an actual example with my simple action code

```
export const GET_POSTS = 'GET_POSTS'

export function getPosts ( posts ) {
  // posts = Array of objects right here

  return {
    type: GET_POSTS,
    posts
  }
}
```

(separate file for categories)

```
export const GET_CATEGORIES = 'GET_CATEGORIES'

export function getCategories ( categories ) {
  // categories = Array of objects right here

  return {
    type: GET_CATEGORIES,
    categories
  }
}
```

..and reducer code

```
import { GET_POSTS } from './actions'

function posts (state = {}, action) {
  const { posts } = action
  // posts = Array of objects right here

  switch(action.type) {
    case GET_POSTS :
      return {
        ...state,
        posts
      }
    default :
      return state
  }
}

export default posts
```

(separate file for categories)

```
import { GET_CATEGORIES } from './actions'

function categories (state = {}, action) {
  const { categories } = action
  // categories = Array of objects right here

  switch(action.type) {
    case GET_CATEGORIES :
      return {
        ...state,
        categories
      }
    default :
      return state
  }
}

export default categories
```

combined in appReducer.js

```
import categories from './Categories/reducer';
import posts from './Posts/reducer';
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

export default combineReducers({
  categories,
  posts
})
```

for some reason after reducing the state, I have to do this to get my arrays

```
function mapStateToProps ({ posts, categories }) {
  // posts and categories no longer arrays. each are an object with a single property that is the array
  posts = posts.posts ? posts.posts : []
  categories = categories.categories ? categories.categories : []

  return {
    posts,
    categories
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the action which updates the posts?

Comment: Yep. It's just a fetch for existing posts, not doing anything complex. Just updated my question to include it.

Comment: @MichaelR can you show the code when you create the store and include all the reducers?

Comment: yes, updated post. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`combineReducers`](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/combineReducers.html#combinereducersreducers) maps reducers to your state and only passes the slice of state that matches the name of the reducer into the reducer. This means that the slice of state passed into your posts Reducer is `state.posts`. Your reducer should therefore return an array of posts and not the full state.

```
function posts (state = [], action) {
  const { posts } = action
  // posts = Array of objects right here

  switch(action.type) {
    case GET_POSTS :
      return posts;
    default :
      return state;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in this reducer

```
import { GET_POSTS } from './actions'

function posts (state = {}, action) {
  const { posts } = action
  // posts = Array of objects right here

  switch(action.type) {
    case GET_POSTS :
      return {
        ...state,
        posts
      }
    default :
      return state
  }
}

export default posts
```

You should do the following

```
return posts;
```

Instead of doing this

```
return {
  ...state,
  posts
};
```

Because posts is an array, when you put that in a new object declaration, it will store it as a new prop. It will be the same as the following code

```
return {
  ...state
  posts: posts
};
```

Also the initialization needs to be changed, as you said the posts itself is an array

```
import { GET_POSTS } from './actions'

function posts (state = [], action) {
  const { posts } = action
  // posts = Array of objects right here

  switch(action.type) {
    case GET_POSTS :
      return posts;
    default :
      return state
  }
}
```